# Split in crystal report IFieldObject

Tags: asp.net, selection, crystal-reports-2008

I'm receiving data to the crystal report IFieldObject in the format of "IFR - Issued For Review".I need to split it from "-" and display only "IFR".How can i achieve this using selection expert of IFieldObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it work by adding Formula Field with the following formula

```
split({dtSquadCheckDetails.RevisionStatus},"-")[1]
```